# When to use @angular tags in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, angular2-routing

I was trying to bootstrap my application using code below in a `boot.ts` file:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router'

import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

It worked fine.

Now I wanted to try and add Google Maps so imported `angular2-google-maps` package , created a `map.component.ts` file and added this to the router mapping (defined in the `app.component.ts` file).

For the above package, `import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';`
is used in the [plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/YX7W20?p=preview) (provided as a starter code).

Now the map is displaying if I add a `<map>` selector in my `index.html` page.

I want it to follow the routing which was defined earlier.

Bootstrapping is also happening twice (once for the `AppComponent` and once for the `Map`)

How to bootstrap the map component properly so that bootstrapping happens only for the Main app?

Also what is the difference between `@angular` and `angular2` packages and when to use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@angular` is for RC (release candidate) versions and `angular2` for beta versions.

In RC versions, for example, `angular2/core` becomes `@angular/core`. You can also notice that the SystemJS configuration is different since you don't have bundled JS files.

Now you need to configure Angular2 modules into map and packages blocks of your SystemJS configuration. See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: So, I will have to convert the plunker code to angular RC version?

Comment: Also is there any difference between `/platform/browser` and `platform-browser-dynamic` ?

Comment: You should bootstrap only once. One for the AppComponent. The map component will be used within this component and not in the `index.html` file... Yes you need to use the RC version.

Comment: the `bootstrap` function is provided by the `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic` module

Answer (score 1):

This is new for Angular2 versions after beta.x, and therefore `=> Angular2 RC.0`

Versions `<= Angular2 beta.x` use `angular2`